# MVC app facebook passing object from view to controller at submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook

I'm developing a faceboook app with framework MVC.
Today I should pass an object from View to Controller, but after the POST in the controller I can't see the compiled object.

Controller's code is like:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [FacebookAuthorize("email", "user_photos")]
 public async Task<ActionResult> SaveReview(FacebookContext context, ExampleModel model)
 {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
       return View();
    }
    return View("Error");
 }
```

And View's code is like:

```
@using AppFBReview.Models
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Models
@model ExampleModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveReview", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ExampleParameter)
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

Someone can tell me why? 
Thanks.

Comment: what you've tried?please post some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer, when I posted to controller with meta-data **FacebookAuthorize**, the post has **redirected** to facebook's servers (to authenticate me), and I **lost** post's data.

Comment: How did you overcome this issue?

Comment: I have same problem, when using FacebookAuthorize meta-data. Any idea how to solve it?