# Post complex model to controller MVC using Facebook application template C#

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-c#-sdk

I have following model:

```
class HomePageModel
{
  public User user { get; set; }
  public ResultHistory resultHistory { get; set; }
  public Option option { get; set; }

  public HomePageModel()
  {
  }
}
```

Code from controller when passing it into view:

```
    [FacebookAuthorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Context context)
    {
        ViewBag.AppUrl = GlobalFacebookConfiguration.Configuration.AppUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<MyAppUser>();
            var option = new Option();
            //CODE for reading user from db, simpified
            Users dbUser = db.Get(context);
            var resultHistory = new ResultHistory(dbUser.NSPGW, dbUser.NSPGL, 
                              dbUser.NMPGW,dbUser.NMPGL,dbUser.NDPGW, dbUser.NDPGL);
            HomepageModel homepageModel = new HomepageModel();
            homepageModel.option = option;
            homepageModel.resultHistory = resultHistory;
            homepageModel.user = user;

            return View(homepageModel);
        }
    }
```

Code from controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Start", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id="opcijeForm"}))
{ 
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="sp" />SP
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="mp" />MP
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="start" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="spoption">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.option.sl, Model.option.slSelectList)
                <label style="padding-left:10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="bb" /> BB
                </label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.option.swt, Model.option.swtSelectList, new {id="bbdd" })
                <label style="padding-left:10px">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ziv" /> ziv
                </label>
               @* @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.gameOption.sln, Model.option.slnSelectList, new { id="zivdd"})*@
            </div>
            <div id="mpoption">
                <label>Numer of oppointment</label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.option.spn, Model.option.spnSelectList)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.option.smv, Model.option.smvSelectList)
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and receiving model on post

```
    [FacebookAuthorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Start(HomepageModel model)
    {
    //Some code
    //here is for example model.option null
    }
```

When I submit form with above model, in my controller action where I receive same model, all it's properties are null.Each class that is within HomePage has only string and int as properties. If I move something, for example from class Option and put it in HomePageModel direct, then properties I have moved are not null. Is there a way to post model as above, or should I just copy properties from these three class into HomePageModel class?

[EDIT]
It is because of meta-data FacebookAuthorize, when I remove it everything is working

[MVC app facebook passing object from view to controller at submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700304/mvc-app-facebook-passing-object-from-view-to-controller-at-submit)

Comment: No one can guess what you have done wrong from this. You need to show your controller methods and the view!

Comment: Are you using strongly typed view? Please post the view

Comment: Whats important is the code for generating the controls! If its not posting back its because the `name` attributes of you controls are not correct

Comment: If you don't post the view showing how you generate the controls, no one can help.

Comment: I add from view part where generating controls from model.option

Comment: Not clear why you mixing htmlhelpers (which will work if used correctly) with manual markup. Your radio button group wont bind to anything (its `name` attribute is `"radio"` but `HomePageModel` does not contain a property named `radio`. Ditto for your checkboxes which don't even have a `name` attribute so won't post back. Assuming properties `sl`, `swt`, `sln`, `spn` and `smv` of `Option ` are public and have getters and setters, then they should bind correctly. If not the post the model for `Option`.

Comment: And I assume `Model.gameOption.slnSelectList` is a typo

Comment: slnSelectList is type of IEnumerable<SelectListItem> and sln is string. Same for others when displaying in dropdown

Comment: No I mean the `gameOption` bit - `HomepageModel` does not contain a property named `gameOption`

Comment: Ignore it, I have it commented in code for now